# How to Format JavaScript String based on value

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I have a string variable object value in this format:

```
["
      traffic                 
    Landing Hits: 0, Rewards Hits: 0        
      engagement
    Facebook Posts: 0, Twitter Tweets: 0, Twitter Autofollows: 0, Instagram Photos: 0, Instagram Likes: 0, Instagram Votes: 0, Pinterest Pins: 0, Form Submissions: 0        
      conversion 
    Submissions: 0, Engagement: 0, Views: 0, Prints: 0
"]
```

I want to convert it into:

```
["traffic", "Landing Hits: 0", "Rewards Hits: 0"],
["engagement",  "Facebook Likes: 0", "Facebook Posts: 0", "Facebook Share: 0", "Form Submissions: 0", "Instagram Likes: 0", "Instagram Photos: 0", "Instagram Votes: 0", "Pinterest Pins: 0", "Twitter Autofollows: 0", "Twitter Tweets: 0"],
["conversion", "Conversion Rate: 0", "Offers Emailed: 0", "Prints: 0", "Submissions: 0", "Views: 0"]
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: you don't have a `string variable object value`, you have an array with a string as the first and only element - and I take it that's the output of some console log or something, because as it stands it's not valid javascript

Comment: Where does the formatting in the string come from?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to do any advanced regex to split this into an array of arrays. Here's a simple (but perhaps not the best) solution:

```js
var before = "\t\t\ttraffic\n\t\tLanding Hits: 0, Rewards Hits: 0\n\t\t\tengagement\n\t\tFacebook Posts: 0, Twitter Tweets: 0, Twitter Autofollows: 0, Instagram Photos: 0, Instagram Likes: 0, Instagram Votes: 0, Pinterest Pins: 0, Form Submissions: 0\n\t\t\tconversion\n\t\tSubmissions: 0, Engagement: 0, Views: 0, Prints: 0";

var pieces = before.replace(/\t/g, '').split('\n');

var group;
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < pieces.length; i++) {
  if (i % 2) {
    result.push(group.concat(pieces[i].split(/\s*,\s*/)));
  } else {
    group = [pieces[i]];
  }
}
console.log(result);
```